# Recursive loop using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to manipulate n-level deep array/object using lodash. Recursive map function or using a loop is not a perfect solution.

I have sample object like this, on key, it could be array or object. I want to manipulate key value in a single go to false using loop it tedious way. Do I can manipulate using lodash to completely change the value to boolean or something else.

```
var a = {key1:true, key2:true, key3:[{key1:true, key5:true}], key6:true};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [cloneDeepWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeepWith) to achieve the same result.

```
var result = _.cloneDeepWith(a, function(v) {
  if(!_.isObject(v)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```js
var a = {
  key1: true,
  key2: true,
  key3: [{
    key1: true,
    key5: true
  }],
  key6: true
};

var result = _.cloneDeepWith(a, function(v) {
  if(!_.isObject(v)) {
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: this won't work actually, because the callback will be only called once for the whole object

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko have you tried running the snippet? It definitely works. Additionally, it's not only called once, but will be called until it traverses the entire object tree.

Comment: But what if you want to modify all the keys *without* cloning? I'm asking regarding a very large tree, which consists of functions that each should re-saved as a *binded* function to a `this` context

Comment: @vsync I think a simple recursion will be optimal in this scenario, since we're not cloning anything.

Comment: Well, I've asked this in the context of *lodash* and not of implementing a recursive function, however easy it may be (and it is) 

Comment: Well technically you can still use `cloneDeepWith()`, in assumption that you do not need to know the key that you're operating in. You can check the parameter value if it's a function, then bind the function with the context that you want.

Comment: Hmm, now that I've thought about it, you mentioned, that you want the tree mutated instead of cloned. The only way I could think of, from the lodash perspective would be to use `cloneDeep` and `mergeWith()` afterwards, but this might be quite an expensive solution.

Comment: @vsync Here's a [possible solution](https://jsfiddle.net/zh2kscq6/1/) using the method above.

Comment: The version I'm using is 4.7.4 which is technically lodash 4. Can you provide the specific version you're using?